# How to check all check boxes are checked or not in a ASP.NET gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I find out if all the check boxes in a ASP.NET grid view are checked or not?

Depending on this I have to gray out a button. I have to enable the button depending on all check boxes being checked.

How do I do this and on which event do I have to place my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell you exactly where to put the code without knowing some more about your page and how the checkboxes get (un)checked, but the general pattern for doing this check would be something like this:

```
protected void checkCheckBoxes()
{
    bool allCheckBoxesChecked = true;

    // Go through each row in the gridview
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        // Go through every control in the row
        foreach (Control control in row.Controls)
        {
            // Control is the superclass so we can't tell what type it is 
            // Best we can do is examine the control ID...
            if (control.ID.Contains("CheckBox"))
            {
                // Cast the control to a CheckBox so we can examine the Checked property
                if (((CheckBox)control).Checked == false)
                {
                    // If the CheckBox isn't checked, we set our flag
                    allCheckBoxesChecked = false;

                    // Would be nice here to be able to break out of both loops but there's no doublebreak statement in C# :-(
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Enable the button based on the value of the flag
    Button1.Enabled = allCheckBoxesChecked;
```

}

This is a similar answer to Scott Mitchell's answer, but will work with multiple checkboxes in the row.

Comment: the way my app works is:
I do have a grid with 3 or 4 rows for example. once user clicks on the row select link it will bring up the formview which contian this checkbox. user clicks on check box and will do update and automatically the check box in the grid view selected..and its grayed out by default(check box in grid view). once i did the updates for all records in the grid the check boxes in the grid will be checked..now all check boxes checkout then i need to enable a button which approves all those records in the grid...

Comment: @Sunny43 Can you edit your question and add the markup for your page? I can't visualise it. Is the checkbox in the FormView or the Gridview?

Comment: its both on grid and formview and both are in sync. if user updates in formview it will change in gridview. I just found a workaround to fix this. I am getting a count from database to check..my problem solved. and my apologizes if i am unable explain my problem correctly...thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment on Nick's answer, I see that you prefer to do this on the server-side. My one word of warning here is that in order to accomplish this you would need to set the CheckBox's AutoPostBack property to True, which means each time a user checks or unchecks a checkbox there is going to be a postback. This can lead to a less than optimal user experience.

### Server-Side Solution

With that out of the way, here's how you'd do it server-side. First, I presume you have a TemplateField in your GridView that contains a CheckBox? You need to set its `AutoPostBack` property to True and create a `CheckChanged` event handler for it. (You can create the event handler by going to the Designer and choosing Edit Templates from the GridView's smart tag. Then, select the Template and double-click the CheckBox.)

Here is my GridView markup for this example. Note the CheckBox's configuration - here, `AutoPostBack` is set to True and the server-side `OnCheckChanged` event is wired up to a server-side event handler, `chkSelected_CheckChanged`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="dsProducts">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelected" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    oncheckedchanged="chkSelected_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" 
            SortExpression="ProductName" />
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The `chkSelected_CheckedChanged` event handler my code-behind class, loops through the GridView's rows. For each row I reference the CheckBox (`chkSelected`) and see if it's checked. If it's *not*, then I can disable my button (`btnDoSomething`). If I loop through all GridView rows and none of them are *not* checked then I know I am to enable my button.

```
protected void chkSelected_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Iterate through all of the rows in the grid and see if there is any unchecked CheckBox
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProducts.Rows)
    {
        var cb = row.FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
        if (!cb.Checked)
        {
            btnDoSomething.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    // If we reach here, all checkboxes are checked, so enable btnDoSomething
    btnDoSomething.Enabled = true;
}
```

### Client-Side Solution

The server-side solution is pretty straightforward, but has the drawback of requiring a postback each time a CheckBox is checked/unchecked. I'd highly suggest using a client-side approach. It's actually quite easy using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Here, the GridView markup is the same as before except the CheckBox does *not* cause a postback (that is, `AutoPostBack` is False) and there's no server-side event handler:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="dsProducts">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelected" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

All the magic happens on the client-side. Presuming you have referenced the jQuery library, your JavaScript code would just be the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=gvProducts.ClientID%> input[id*='chkSelected']:checkbox").click(EnableDisableButtonAsNeeded);

        EnableDisableButtonAsNeeded();
    });

    function EnableDisableButtonAsNeeded() {
        var totalCheckboxes = $("#<%=gvProducts.ClientID%> input[id*='chkSelected']:checkbox").size();
        var checkedCheckboxes = $("#<%=gvProducts.ClientID%> input[id*='chkSelected']:checkbox:checked").size();

        if (totalCheckboxes == checkedCheckboxes)
            $("#<%=btnDoSomething.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $("#<%=btnDoSomething.ClientID %>").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
</script>
```

I created a client-side function named `EnableDisableButtonAsNeeded` that determines how many total checkboxes there are in the grid and how many are checked. If those two numbers are equal then it enabled the button, otherwise it disabled it. This function is called once when the page loads as well as every time a checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript. I suggest you read `www.w3schools.com`, specifcally *[Checkbox checked Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp)*.

The main thing you want to do is get the "id" of all your check boxes and cycle through them.